# In java constructor and main which one will execute first?

Tags: java

Basically which one will execute first the main method or the constructor?

```
public class ConstructorExp {
  public ConstructorExp() {
    System.out.println("Ctt");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Inside Main Methos");
    System.out.println("Main");
  }
}
```

Comment: @Sandy in the code so far, your constructor won't be executed at all. Do you understand the concept of an "entry point" of your code?

Comment: The constructor will never run, because you have not created any instances of `ConstructorExp`.

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: Where would you create the instance? You would do it in the `main` method, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main method will always be excecuted first, because it is a special static method that will be called from Java itself to start an application.

For more about the main method please read [Java main() Method Explained](https://www.baeldung.com/java-main-method) for example.

Constructors will be created on object creation - in your case no object creation happens - so the constructor will never be executed.

You could modify your example to also execute the constructor:

```
public class ConstructorExp {
  public ConstructorExp() {
    System.out.println("Ctt");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Inside Main Methos");
    ConstructorExp example = new ConstructorExp();
    System.out.println("Main");
  }
}
```

Be carefully, because the `example` object is never used the constructor call might be eliminated by some kind of optimization depending on the compiler you are using.